# Integrating the sum gives different answer that summing the integrals of the terms

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fractional-calculus

I wrote this code:

```
FractionalD[α_, f_, x_, opts___] := 
  Integrate[(x - t)^(-α - 1) (f /. x -> t), {t, 0, x}, opts]/Gamma[-α]
FractionalD[mu_?Positive, f_, x_, opts___] := 
  Module[{m = Ceiling[mu]},
    D[FractionalD[-(m - mu), f, x, opts], {x, m}]]

FractionalD[
  -α, 
  -((0.012100 x^(-1 + 2 α) α)/Gamma[1 + α]^2) - (0.012100 x^(-2 + 2 α) α^2)/Gamma[1 + α]^2, 
   x, 
   Assumptions -> {x > 0 && Re[β] > -1 && Re[α] > 1/2}]
```

I run that, and *Mathematica* obtained output with  `Hypergeometric2F1`.
But I run one-by-one:

```
FractionalD[α_, f_, x_, opts___] := 
  Integrate[(x - t)^(-α - 1) (f /. x -> t), {t, 0, x}, opts]/Gamma[-α]
FractionalD[mu_?Positive, f_, x_, opts___] := 
  Module[{m = Ceiling[mu]},
    D[FractionalD[-(m - mu), f, x, opts], {x, m}]]

I1 := 
  FractionalD[
    -α, 
    -((0.012100 x^(-1 + 2 α) α)/Gamma[1 + α]^2), 
    x, 
    Assumptions -> {x > 0 && Re[β] > -1 && Re[α] > 1/2}] 
  //
    FullSimplify

 I2 := 
   FractionalD[
     -α, 
     -((0.012100 x^(-2 + 2 α) α^2)/Gamma[1 + α]^2), 
     x, 
     Assumptions -> {x > 0 && Re[β] > -1 && Re[α] > 1/2}] 
   //
     FullSimplify
```

and find the answer which I need. Any suggestion for obtaining the output the same one-by-one? 
And I have problem for two following code:

```
Subscript[u, 1][x] = 
 FractionalD[-\[Alpha], 0.9` - 0.10000000000000002` x, x, 
  Assumptions -> {x > 0 && Re[\[Beta]] > -1 && Re[\[Alpha]] > 1/2}]

Subscript[u, 2][x] = 
 FractionalD[-\[Alpha], 
  8.` Subscript[u, 1][x] - 2.` x Subscript[u, 1][x], x, 
  Assumptions -> {x > 0 && Re[\[Beta]] > -1 && Re[\[Alpha]] > 1/2}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integrate` uses different algorithms based on the form of the integrand.  In order to obtain the output generated by integrating each term separately, add the following

```
FractionalD[α_, f_Plus, x_, opts___] := Map[FractionalD[α, #, x, opts] &, Expand@f]
```

to instruct *Mathematica* to `Map` the integral over addition (`Plus`) in `f`.

Comment: If possible for you, which put complete code.

Comment: I don't know which, where I add: FractionalD[α_, f_Plus, x_, opts___] := Map[FractionalD[α, #, x, opts] &, f]?

Comment: You can insert the line at the very beginning, so that you have a total of 3 lines defining `FractionalD`.

Comment: Many thanks. But I have problem with:  8.` ((0.9` x^\[Alpha])/(\[Alpha] Gamma[\[Alpha]]) - (
    0.10000000000000002` x^(
     1 + \[Alpha]))/((\[Alpha] + \[Alpha]^2) Gamma[\[Alpha]])) - 
 2.` x ((0.9` x^\[Alpha])/(\[Alpha] Gamma[\[Alpha]]) - (
    0.10000000000000002` x^(
     1 + \[Alpha]))/((\[Alpha] + \[Alpha]^2) Gamma[\[Alpha]]))

Comment: @user37694, See my edit: Add `Expand` to `f` to completely expand it out before `Map`ping the integral over addition.  Also please put @QuantumDot  in your comments to let the system give me a "ping" so I know you have added a comment here.

Comment: Many thanks, then this question     http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111563,        also this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
 FractionalD[\[Alpha]_, f_, x_, opts___] := 
 Integrate[(x - t)^(-\[Alpha] - 1) (f /. x -> t), {t, 0, x}, opts]/
  Gamma[-\[Alpha]]
FractionalD[mu_?Positive, f_, x_, opts___] := 
 Module[{m = Ceiling[mu]}, 
  D[FractionalD[-(m - mu), f, x, opts], {x, m}]]

FractionalD[-\[Alpha], (-((0.012100 x^(-1 + 2 \[Alpha]) \[Alpha])/
        Gamma[1 + \[Alpha]]^2) - (0.012100 x^(-2 + 
           2 \[Alpha]) \[Alpha]^2)/Gamma[1 + \[Alpha]]^2) // 
   FullSimplify, x, 
  Assumptions -> {x > 0 && Re[\[Beta]] > -1 && 
     Re[\[Alpha]] > 1/2}] // ExpandAll
```