# How I can get faster code for computing a fractional integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

I use of this code [Fractional Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalIntegral.html) and wrote the following code:

```
INT[α_, f_, x_, opts___] := 
  Integrate[(x - t)^(-α - 1) (f /. x -> t), {t, 0, x}, opts]/Gamma[-α]
INT[mu_?Positive, f_, x_, opts___] := 
  Module[{m = Ceiling[mu]},
    D[INT[-(m - mu), f, x, opts], {x, m}]]
```

I run for:

```
u1[x] = 
  INT[-α, 0.9 - 0.1 x, x, Assumptions -> {x > 0 && Re[β] > -1 && Re[α] > 0}]

u2[x] = 
  INT[-α, 8. u1[x] - 2. x u1[x], x, 
    Assumptions -> {x > 0 && Re[β] > -1 && Re[α] > 0}]
```

But *Mathematica* needs a lot of time to make the calculations. Any suggestion code for get faster calculation?

Comment: your attempt to decompose integral of sums is not as general as needed. For example `u1[x]` is a sum of two terms but `8 u1[x]` has head `Times`. that said I'm puzzled why thats needed at all, but notice `INT[-\[Alpha], u1[x], x, Assumptions...]` returns almost immediately while `INT[-\[Alpha], 8 u1[x], x, Assumptions...]`  does not.

Comment: I wrote this code to obtain u1 and then u2 obtain with u1, and u3 with u2 and ....

Comment: This is a part of Homotopy perturbation iteration method.

Comment: [`FractionalIntegrate`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FractionalIntegrate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two suggestions to speed up the code:

1. Always `Expand` the input expression `f`
2. Set option `GenerateConditions→False` to `Integrate` to bypass convergence test routines.

This `Expand`s the input and passes the result to the integrators `internalINT`:

```
INT[α_, f_, x_, opts___] :=
  Module[{expr = Expand[f]},
    internalINT[α, f, x, opts]
  ]
```

Of the following, the first two definitions for `internalINT` is your code copied here.  The third definition `Map`s the `internalINT` over addition (`Plus`):

```
SetOptions[Integrate, GenerateConditions -> False];

internalINT[α_, f_, x_, opts___] := 
  Integrate[(x - t)^(-α - 1) (f /. x -> t), {t, 0, x}, opts]/Gamma[-α]

internalINT[mu_?Positive, f_, x_, opts___] := 
  Module[{m = Ceiling[mu]}, D[internalINT[-(m - mu), f, x, opts], {x, m}]]

internalINT[α_, f_Plus, x_, opts___] := Map[internalINT[α, #, x, opts] &, Expand@f]
```

Comment: Which code is correct in line four:    " internalINT[mu_?Positive, f_, x_, opts___] := 
 Module[{m = Ceiling[mu]}, D[INT[-(m - mu), f, x, opts], {x, m}]]"        or          "internalINT[mu_?Positive, f_, x_, opts___] := 
 Module[{m = Ceiling[mu]}, 
  D[internalINT[-(m - mu), f, x, opts], {x, m}]]".   Both codes are correct I think!

Comment: @user37694 Both are fine; but `internalINT[mu_?Positive, f_, x_, opts___] := Module[{m = Ceiling[mu]}, D[internalINT[-(m - mu), f, x, opts], {x, m}]]` is preferred.  I simply forgot to replace `INT` with `internalINT`; I have made the appropriate change in the edit.

Comment: Many many thanks.

Comment: @QuantumDot  could you please let me know, can you help me for this code?

Comment: @bahram Yes, I can help you.  What is your question?

Comment: @QuantumDot  Thanks for your time. I reviewed excellent answer  for this question. I tried and I can not write your code for this question:   http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114104/faster-code-for-calculat-in-integral-include-derivative

Comment: @QuantumDot Dear QuantumDot, Do your code is correct for m-1<mu<m?

Comment: @user37694 I don't understand your question.  Would you explain in more detail?

Comment: @QuantumDot  Excuse me. This code is correct. For derivative we need 0<α<1, 1<α<2. Can you help me for this code: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114356/how-i-can-get-faster-code-for-computing-a-fractional-derivative?